Laravel can't get redis key value in For loop
I have a problem with Laravel when getting a Redis value in loop
public function testLoop()
{
    for($i = 0; $i < 3; $i++) {

        Redis::set('key_'.$i, 'value_'.$i);
        Log::info(Redis::get('key_'.$i));
    }
   
    return true;
}

Laravel successfully set the key but any error while trying to get key
here is the logs, it only gets first

[2024-10-21 09:05:13] local.INFO: value_0
[2024-10-21 09:05:13] local.ERROR: Error while reading line from the server. [tcp://docker.for.mac.localhost:6379] {"userId":569,"exception":"[object] (Predis\Connection\ConnectionException(code: 0): Error while reading line from the server. [tcp://docker.for.mac.localhost:6379] at /var/www/html/vendor/predis/predis/src/Connection/AbstractConnection.php:144)
[stacktrace]

and here is the redis key

I'm tried both predis and phpredis but both have same issue
I have set redis timeout to 0
127.0.0.1:6379> config get timeout
1) "timeout"
2) "0"

I've also set read_write_timeout in config/database.php to 0
'read_write_timeout' => 0,


value from redis-cli

redis-cli monitor (stuck at key_1)



i think i found the problem
it's because a PHP version, I'm using docker image
php:8.3-rc-fpm-buster
I change the PHP version to 8.2 and 8.3.7
It works well


did you get the value in redis console ?

@Nageen yes,, i have the value ,, i was update the picture,, please see

As stated here https://stackoverflow.com/a/11931651/6051839, try to set read_write_timeout to -1

@IliaYatsenko yes I do,, I read that thread before. but still have same error

did you try to use sleep before get
or after for loop, you can Redis::get("key_4");
